# PHP break up for each loop in Magento Unicenta product update script

Tags: php, magento

I have a ForEach loop in an extension for Magento that is hitting a hard-wall with my shared host MySQL server. The script is taking too long to execute and the MySQL server shuts down the connection. Obviously I cannot just have the hosting platform increase the time-out, because as more products are added, that time-out would need to be increased. The only viable option I can see is to split up the foreach loop.

Here is the function:

```
$ps=Mage::getModel('unicentaopos/productstock');
$ps->loadProductHash();//load a hash of history
$ps->noImageProducts();//load products without images so that if change is detected we load them.

if (is_a($mode,'Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule')){
    $ps->configSim();
}else{
    $ps->configSim($mode);
}
$db=Mage::Helper('unicentaopos')->getUnicentaOposConnection();
$productsTable=Mage::Helper('unicentaopos')->getTableName(self::TABLE_PRODUCTS);
if (is_null($db))return false;
$sql="select * from `$productsTable`";
$rows=$db->query($sql);
if (is_null($rows)) return false;

foreach  ($rows as $row){
    $ps->getUnicentaProducts($row);
    $ps->doImage($row);
}
$ps->updateMagentoProducts();
return true;
```

Now the function currently has a lot of logging enabled, and from what I can tell in the log it gets to item number 1017 before it errors out each time. There are currently 1088 products/items but that number will grow. I was thinking to split it up so that it processes no more than say 500 per round into the database, then picks up where it left off and does another 500, but when it reaches the true end it stops. Can anyone help me figure this out, I know programming in a few languages but this is completely foreign to me.

Comment: You could use a for loop instead, that way you can simply save the last key and continue from there

Comment: Maybe you can close the connection yourself before the loop and reconnect afterward?
Do you do any sql work inside the loop? if you do, try to batch it and commit in only after the loop

Comment: The whole loop is going into one MySQL database grabbing all of the products and then adding into another MySQL database. This script is designed to run once an hour, and to sync all of the products from the local UniCentaoPOS database to Magento, adding any new products that have been created in UniCenta. Due to the confines of my shared hosting environment I am trying to set this whole thing to happen in multiple loops. Unfortunately, I am fairly uncertain how to accomplish this task.